# Can BeEF hooking be stopped with Content Security Policies

Tags: xss, content-security-policy, beef

I know that using strict values for default-src and scripts-src are a popular way to prevent (or at least limit the impact) of XSS attacks. But I was just wondering it CSPs can be used to stop attackers/pentesters from hooking browsers using the BeEF framework.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to stop someone from using the BeEF framework against your website by sending a CSP directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The Beef hook is just an advanced payload for an XSS attack that relies upon the script-src tag. If you have a healthy Content-Security-Policy, victims browser will refuse to load the external beef hook.

CSP is a secondary line of defense in case you have a HTML-injection vulnerability.

Comment: well, except for bypasses to CSP, such as -- http://ruxcon.org.au/assets/slides/CSP-kuza55.pptx -- and the more-recent work on the subject.

Comment: @atdre Bypasses to CSP are actually security bugs in the browser in some cases or just an incorrectly implemented CSP on the web application. The defense mechanism is there, whether it's well implemented is a different problem